# Mutating Trigger Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, mutating-table

I have two tables `main` and `hist`. I want to copy a row from `main` table whenever its datetime column is modified to `hist` and reset the  modified colums in the `main` to `null` except one column. However I am getting mutating trigger error. Please help.
Below are the two triggers,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INS_HIS
AFTER UPDATE OF datetime ON main
FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO HIST 
    VALUES (Col2 = :new.col2, Col3= :new.Col3)
END;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPD_NUL_MAIN
AFTER INSERT ON HIST
FOR EACH ROW
   UPDATE Main 
      SET (Col2 = NULL
           Col3= NULL)
    WHERE HIST.datetime = main.datetime;
END
```

Comment: Hey Rob , i think the error is with second trigger, the columns are copied to hist table but after that when it has to make the main columns null it doesnt work.

Comment: Yep - I saw the error of my ways (I didn't notice the AFTER UPDATE of datatime) and deleted the original comment.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to change only the row in main that triggered the update, you can get rid of the second trigger altogether if you change your first trigger to a BEFORE UPDATE one and set col2 and col3 there:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INS_HIS
BEFORE UPDATE OF datetime ON main
FOR EACH ROW          
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO HIST
    (col2,
     col3)
  VALUES
    (:new.col2,
     :new.Col3);
  :new.col2 := NULL;
  :new.col3 := NULL;
END;
```

BTW: your trigger syntax is wrong - you cannot use (col2 = :new.col2).

Comment: Apologies - distracted during writing the post and it looks like I've submitted a duplicate answer!

Comment: No problem, happens to me all the time :-)

Comment: ohh yeah u r right abt the syntax, my bad, but the null thing in the same trigger wont happen

Comment: @user3110283 Did you actually try it (as a BEFORE UPDATE trigger)? If yes, what *exactly* didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this I think you only need one trigger?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ins_his BEFORE UPDATE OF datetime ON main
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO hist ( col2     , col3      )
            VALUES ( :new.col2, :new.col3 );

  :new.col2 := NULL;
  :new.col3 := NULL;

END;
/
```

Example output:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Dec 17 13:17:08 2013

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management,
OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create table main ( datetime DATE, col2 NUMBER, col3 NUMBER );

Table created.

SQL> create table hist ( col2 NUMBER, col3 NUMBER );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ins_his BEFORE UPDATE OF datetime ON main
  2  FOR EACH ROW
  3  BEGIN
  4    --
  5    INSERT INTO hist ( col2     , col3      )
  6              VALUES ( :new.col2, :new.col3 );
  7    --
  8    :new.col2 := NULL;
  9    :new.col3 := NULL;
 10    --
 11  END;
 12  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into main( datetime, col2, col3 )
  2  values ( sysdate, 5, 10 );

1 row created.

SQL> select * from main;

DATETIME        COL2       COL3
--------- ---------- ----------
17-DEC-13          5         10

SQL> select * from hist;

no rows selected

SQL> update main set datetime = sysdate-1;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from main;

DATETIME        COL2       COL3
--------- ---------- ----------
16-DEC-13

SQL> select * from hist;

      COL2       COL3
---------- ----------
         5         10

SQL>
```

Comment: Are you sure this works with an AFTER UPDATE trigger (instead of a BEFORE UPDATE one)?

Comment: Ahh i dont think we can change the values to null in the same trigger. It wont happen , because the  event is on the main table

Comment: And I had one more question , I would have to edit the trigger every time I add columns to my main table , is there any way where I can select all the columns in my main table to be copied no matter when I add them or delete?

Comment: @user3110283 Please do not ask additional questions in comments. If your problem was fixed, accept one of the answers, and post an additional question on SO (StackOverflow).

Comment: Oh I am sorry , didnt realize. New to SO. Thanks.